# Custom UITableViewDelefate doesnt work at all

Tags: ios5, uitableview

So, Im following this great tutorial at http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2 to get started with iOS programming.

And I decided that I would like to have custom made headers for my table, and as always I found lots of info here on stackoverflow, that I should implement the method viewForHeaderInSection in my UITableViewDelegate.

So, since I'm using storyboard I thought I'd create my own class of UITableView and then use it for my table in the storyboard.

I have also selected "MyTableView" as "Class" under "Custom Class" in the"Identity inspector" for my table.

My subclass of UITableView (MyTableView.h) looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/Uikit.h>

@interface MyTableView : UITableView <UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

And MyTableView.m looks like:

```
#import "MyTableView.h"

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self) {
         self.delegate = self;
   }
   return self;
}

// and then viewForHeaderInSection and heightForHeaderInSection is implemented below...

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be subclassing UITableViewController and not UITableView.
when adding a new file to your project (choose : Cocoa touch -> Objective-c class) you should choose subclass of "UITableViewController"

your .h file should look like this

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController
@end
```

in the .m file you should implement `viewForHeaderInsection` and `heightForHeaderInSection`
then go to your storyboard and drag a "UITableViewController" from the objects library.
set the class to MyTableViewController.

Comment: I did subclass The controller aswell, I just wanted a delegate to deal with it. Anyway I ended up making the Controller delegate for the TableView

Comment: the controller should be the delegate. UITableViewController conforms to UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols, so when you subclass it you should implement the methods in the protocols.